# Pass url using js without href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an anchor with href, when i click on this anchor it opens facebook sharer with the url located in the href, i don't want it to be with the href, i want to pass this url on click so it opens the popup of the sharer and inside the sharer i want the url that i passed, how can i do that? here is my code:

```js
$(".facebooksharer").on('click', function() {
  window.location = "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=[MYURL]";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="facebooksharer" href="#" target="_blank">Fb</a>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate the question??

Comment: @Strikers updated

Comment: since you want a pop up. Can I expect it to be inside the same page?? IN that cas I would advice you to have an additional div floating on the html with a iframe in it. initally set the src of iframe to be null but when user clicks  on the link you can populate the iframe with the desired url.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
$(".facebooksharer").on('click', function(){
    window.open("https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u="+YourUrl, '_blank');
});
```

This will open a new tab with whatever url you want.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right you can do that with a custom attribute :

```
$(".facebooksharer").on('click', function(){
     window.location = "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u="+$(this).attr("data-url");
});

<a class="facebooksharer" href="#" data-url="theurlyouwant" target="_blank">
Fb</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also used above code for Open URL

```
 var url = "http://www.example.com";
 window.open(url, '_blank');
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not getting you wrong use custom attribute to keep sharer url in HTML.

```
<a class="facebooksharer" href="#"  data-url="sharerUrlWhichYouWantToOpen" target="_blank">Fb</a>
```

To open that in pop up use window.open method as below:
assuming your page is having jQuery here is click handler for facebook share button:

```
$(".facebooksharer").on('click', function() {
  var url = "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + $(this).attr('data-url');
  window.open(url,'_blank','height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes');
});
```